# how to invoke method sent through post request from forms application to a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, post

I need to send some data through http post from my windows forms application to a url. I will be sending a string parameter in this post request. In my C# method i will be validating the parameter and send a response Y or N to the forms application. 
My problem is I don't know how to invoke the method in website which is called from forms application. So far i can see the data is posted on to the server and in response i am getting the whole web page. I have no idea how to invoke that particular method in C# and get the response in forms application.

Below is my forms application code

```
        public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
        os.Close();
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        if (resp == null) return null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
```

I am giving call to the above method

```
String message =     HttpPost(@"http://localhost/Home.aspx/postMessageCall","A1234");
```

postMessageCall is the method which i want to invoke

Now where and how do i need to write the postMessageCall method so that this method gets invoked everytime when i specify the above url.

Please help..

Comment: Try using a generic handler (.ashx) instead of a web form. Then, in the handler's `ProcessRequest` you can return whatever you want.  You should consider passing the method name as one of your POST variables.  You could also just have a separate handler class for each of your methods.  Setup mappings if you don't want the file extension to be required in the URL.

Comment: Can you please provide any example..

Comment: @Lorek : How can i access the parameter value which i am sending through the post request in the handler.. I am able to get the message which I want to display but i need to validate the input before sending the response

Comment: @Lorek : Thanks a lot Lorek. I got the solution..

Comment: Sorry, I crashed right after I wrote that post. It feels better the more you figure out on your own, though. Good job.